# How to exclude specific file from babel-loader when using vue-cli setup?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, vue-cli, babel-loader

There is an option `transpileDependencies` in `vue.config.js` that can be configured to all modules from `node_modules`, that should be transpiled, although `node_modules` is normally excluded.

What I'm looking for is something like the oposite:
I have some third party code, that is not within `node_modules` and already available as quite large ES2015 UMD module. (Needlessly) transpiling this takes quite some time and sometimes doesn't finish at all. Hence, I'd like to configure this path to be *excluded* from babel transpiliation. Putting this module under `node_modules` currently is no option.

So is there a simple way to configure a path from being excluded in the babel-loader?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you can use your `babel.config.js` to ignore babel process

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  presets: [],
  plugins: [],
  exclude: [
    path.resolve('file path')
  ]
}
```

see there
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#ignore

Comment: doesn't seem to be working with docker